# Azure SignalR serverless arm template

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-signalr

Is it possible to set the SignalR mode ( Default || Serverless || Classic )
inside a arm template?

Snapshot from my currently used arm template:

```
 "resources": [
    {
        "comments": "SignalR serverless arm ressource",
        "type": "Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Free_F1",
            "tier": "Free",
            "size": "F1",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "name": "[parameters('SignalR_Name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
        "location": "potatocountry",
        "tags": {
            "CostCenter": "-",
            "Product": "signalr",
            "Team": "t5"
        },
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "hostNamePrefix": null
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
```

With this template SignalR is generated in Default mode. Serverless mode is desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I don't see this exposed in the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/signalr/signalr/createorupdate#signalrcreateorupdateproperties) definition. I don't see it in `resources.azure.com` and I don't see it when exporting the template. So I guess the answer is: "No" for now.

**UPDATE**

Actually, this is what portal does:

```
/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/name/providers/Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR/name/switchFeatures?api-version=2018-10-01
```

with this payload:

```
{"features":[{"flag":"ServiceMode","value":"Serverless"}]}
```

try something like:

```
"type": "Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR/switchFeatures",
"name": "[concat(parameters('SignalR_Name'), '/doesntmatter')]",
"apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
"location": "xxx",
"properties": {
     "features": [{
          "flag":  "ServiceMode",
          "value": "Serverless"
     }]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be true. Do you know if there is any possibility to set the mode inside the "properties" section?

Comment: updated the answer, arm template probably wont help, but it might

Comment: I tested with the updated answer, adding `{"features":[{"flag":"ServiceMode","value":"Serverless"}]}` to `properties` in the ARM-template. And I can confirm that it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like ARM templates exported from the portal now have this.